# How do I kill a running node once I close the terminal I launched it in?

Tags: nodes, frontend, command

I was running a Substrate node on my system but unknowingly I didn't stop the node by using 'CTRL+C' and closed the editor. After that I could see that on frontend, my node was running continuously even though it is was no longer running in the editor.

So there might be a reason that it is still running in the backend of my system but I am not able to see it. So how to stop that node?

Comment: Consider describing the issue in more detail and make the title more descriptive.

Comment: Which operating system are you on? Is this a server or a desktop computer? What node are you running? Can you see it in the task manager/process viewer? What do you mean by "editor"?

Comment: `ps -aux | grep polkadot` and then `kill -9 process_id_here` will work for linux

Answer (score 6):

This question is not specific to Substrate or Polkadot, but we are glad to help you. Pressing `Ctrl+C` in a terminal does the same as sending the `INT` signal to the running process. The simplest way to stop it is to run the following in another terminal and press `Y` on the processes you want to interrupt.

```bash
killall -s INT -i polkadot
```